# Does Contact Editor Extension work with Version 5.6.1?

Tags: contacts, extension

I just upgraded to version 5.6.1 from 5.3.1. I tried using the contact editor extension to change a contact type but when I select "Change Contact Type" it take me to the CiviCRM homepage. I use CiviCRM with WordPress.

Does the Contact Editor extension work with 5.6.1?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the CiviCRM cache?

Answer (score 2):

This happens when the menu link is not registered properly for all extensions. I always have a habit of performing cleanup cache and some times delete template_c and rebuild menu.

In your case as @Tony said after performing cleanup cache the menu should be registered and the extension should work. You can do this by navigating to CiviCRM >> Administer >> System Settings >> Cleanup Caches and Update Paths >> Cleanup caches.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it.  I'll just add that step when I upgrade.

Comment: So can this be marked as answered so that it will help others.

Comment: I cleaned the cache, but the menu Option "Change contact type" did not show in the Actions menu when opened from particular contact profile.

Any other ways to update menu / look for the issue?